# Kivy install failed with pip Mac OS Sierra

Tags: python, macos, pip, kivy

I get the following error message:

```
    *bytes, CFIndex length, CFAllocatorRef bytesDeallocator);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

> error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

I used this command:

> "//anaconda/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/sg/p9ztjwgx1v1cctrr2hmdymcr0000gp/T/pip-build-y_mai_3m/kivy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /var/folders/sg/p9ztjwgx1v1cctrr2hmdymcr0000gp/T/pip-_3c7ty_r-record/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in
>   /private/var/folders/sg/p9ztjwgx1v1cctrr2hmdymcr0000gp/T/pip-build-y_mai_3m/kivy/

What could be the reason, how to solve this problem?

Comment: please add some context to your question and format your code properly.

Comment: Someone will help you quicker if you provide [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, as Cython was located inside anaconda pip couldn't install kivy, and used pip3 to install Cython and so kivy, now it is installed :) thanks people

Comment: You are good, I try to make your question now acceptable. Good luck here on the stackexchange!